# How to create different links for one page with realurl?

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

Is it possible to produce two different speaking urls for one TYPO3 page using realurl?

I’ve got a page that has **title=News1** and **nav_title=NI001**

With Apache2, TYPO3 7.6.18 and realurl 2.2.0 configured with almost default values I get the following link:

```
domain/level1/level2/year1/NI001.html
```

and of course

```
domain/index.php?id=XXX
```

This is the default behaviour and this is fine so far. Now what I would like to know is, if it is possible to get these three different links produced with realurl all pointing to the same page:

```
domain/level1/level2/year1/News1.html

domain/NI001.html
```

and of course

```
domain/index.php?id=XXX
```

Now there is one more point. I've got the pages in different levels. So I'll have to be able to handle this situation:

```
domain/level1/level2/year1/News1.html
domain/level1/level2/year2/News2.html
domain/level1/year3/News3.html
```

as

```
domain/NI001.html
domain/NI002.html
domain/NI003.html
```

Could a special combination of realurl and .htaccess help us with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Dmitry Dulepov:

> It is essential to understand these two points, so here they are
>   again:
>
> 1. Realurl only encodes what it gets from TYPO3
> 2. Realurl has no way to
>      know whether the URL is correct or not. It always encodes it as is
>      and passes the encoded version back to TYPO3.

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#realurl-does-not-work

So the answer is no.